# python setup.py bdist_rpm error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, setup.py, rpmbuild

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

RPM version: 4.11.1

python 3.4

I use `sudo python setup.py bdist --formats=rpm`, it occurs the same error.